# create a gui for google app script CalendarApp.createEvent()

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create a web app that allows me to set a schedule on my calendar. I know how to create an event and enter the date and time in the arguments. However I want it to be a GUI. I used dateBox(), but it automatically sets the time to midnight. How do I allow my assistant to go to the GUI and select date and time such as a listbox for the month, another listbox for day, another year, and a listbox for time with normal looking time frames such as 9:00am, 4:00pm for both start time and end time, and have it place the meeting on the calendar correctly? If I can just use something similar to the datebox for the date, and create a listbox for the time of day for the meeting that would be great, but the listbox for all of them would work too.

I know it would be easier for her to just go into the calendar and add it, but I want her to ask the client for a couple of dates and times that work for them, enter them in the gui web app, and it sends me an email with the dates and times, and I just confirm which date and time I want, and then it automatically schedules it on the calendar with the correct date and time.

thanks,
   chris

Answer (score 0):

If you still need to solve this problem, there is a nice example of a [calendar application here](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/calendar-services/create-calendar-events-by-submitting-form)

You can adapt it to your liking as necessary, but I think it will point you in the right direction.